# dataSource.filter filters ID which is not visible in frontend

Tags: angularjs, angular, filter

Basically, this is my code

```
  applySearchFilter(filterValue: string) {
this.values = filterValue.toString().toLowerCase();
this.dataSource.filter = this.values;
```

}
with "this.dataSource.filter" I can filter any data out of it, but I want to add an exception to keyId.... See the object below.

my object looks something like this.

```
{
keyId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000010001", 
name: "Test 10",
location: "New York"
}
```

When I input "10", it filters everything in the dataSource that has a 10. So, not only the name has "10" in it, but the keyId too. I took an hour to realize what this kept happening... and it is because of keyId xD

**Allthough I get the whole object with keyId included, keyId is not shown in frontend and should not be search/filter-able. Even if it does not show keyId in frontend, he searches for the object that has that keyid**

I am not sure how to fix it right now, since something like **this.dataSource.data.name** or so does not work...

I'd appreciate if you gals and girls would give me some tips.

Oh and here is where I get my data to that get filtered.

```
  public getObject(): void {
   this.service.getObjectMethod().then(data=> {
   this.dataSource.data = data;
}, (err: Error) => { console.log(err.message); });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this issue using.

```
public filterData(): void {
    if (this.inputValues.trim().length !== 0) {
      this.filteredValues = [];
      this.dataSource.data.filter(data => {
        if (data.name.toLowerCase().includes((this.inputValues).toLowerCase()) ||
          data.opensCategory.toLowerCase().includes((this.inputValues).toLowerCase())) {
          return true && this.filteredValues.push(data);
        }
      });
      this.dataSource.data = this.filteredValues;
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to search.

```js
  applySearchFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (data: any, filterValue: string) {
      return data.name.trim().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0;
    };
  }
```